# Get Current Monday?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have this string that is a date called `strRDate` and another string called `strColor`.
The cutoff date is this weeks Monday.

I would like to be something like this:

```
'// strRDate format is MM/DD/YYYY

Dim strRDate,strColor
strRDate="1/1/1999"
strColor="none"   

 If strRDate is this weeks Monday or older then  <-- HOW DO I DO THIS ???
    strColor="green"
    else 
    strColor="red"
    end if
```

So anything older then Oct 21, 2013 would be green, else it would be red.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' for successful parsing of mm/dd/yyyy dates (1033 is EN_US)
Response.LCID = 1033

Dim strRDate, strColor

strRDate = "10/21/2013"
strColor = GetColor(ParseDate(strRDate))
```

and a few helper functions:

```
Function GetColor(d) 
    GetColor = "none"

    If IsDate(d) Then
        If d <= GetMondayForWeek(Now()) Then
            GetColor = "green"
        Else
            GetColor = "red"
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function ParseDate(strDate)
    ParseDate = vbEmpty
    If IsDate(strDate) Then
        ParseDate = CDate(strDate)
    End If
End Function

Function GetMondayForWeek(d)
    ' midnight
    GetMondayForWeek = CDate(Fix(d))

    While Weekday(GetMondayForWeek) <> vbMonday
      GetMondayForWeek = GetMondayForWeek - 1 
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: I tried it but I get an error Syntax error: Function GetColor(d) ?

Comment: There is no syntax error in my function. I've tested my code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do the calculation like this:

```
strRDate = "1/1/1999"
strColor = "none"

monday = Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1)

If CDate(strRDate) <= monday Then
  strColor="green"
Else 
  strColor="red"
End If
```

[`Weekday(Date, vbMonday)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t51x9wtx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) returns a value between 1 and 7 for each day of the week, with Monday being the first day:

```
Monday    → 1
Tuesday   → 2
Wednesday → 3
Thursday  → 4
Friday    → 5
Saturday  → 6
Sunday    → 7
```

Subtract 1 from the return value of the function and you get the difference in days between the current date and the most recent Monday. Subtracting that difference from the current date gives you the date of the most recent Monday, which you can then compare to your input date (use the [`CDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to convert the string to an actual date).

Answer (score 0):

This date's monday can be calculated by substracting the Weekday() and adjusting for the Weekday of mondays:

```
  WScript.Echo "german locate (dd.mm.yyyy):"
  Dim dtCur : dtCur = #10/10/2013#
  Do Until dtCur > #10/24/2013#
     Dim dtThisMonday      : dtThisMonday      = DateAdd("d", -WeekDay(dtCur) + 2, dtCur)
     Dim isAfterThisMonday : isAfterThisMonday = dtCur > dtThisMonday
     WScript.Echo dtCur, WeekDay(dtCur), WeekdayName(WeekDay(dtCur), True), dtThisMonday, CStr(isAfterThisMonday)
     dtCur = DateAdd("d", 1, dtCur)
  Loop
```

output:

```
german locate (dd.mm.yyyy):
10.10.2013 5 Thu 07.10.2013 True
11.10.2013 6 Fri 07.10.2013 True
12.10.2013 7 Sat 07.10.2013 True
13.10.2013 1 Sun 14.10.2013 False
14.10.2013 2 Mon 14.10.2013 False
15.10.2013 3 Tue 14.10.2013 True
16.10.2013 4 Wed 14.10.2013 True
17.10.2013 5 Thu 14.10.2013 True
18.10.2013 6 Fri 14.10.2013 True
19.10.2013 7 Sat 14.10.2013 True
20.10.2013 1 Sun 21.10.2013 False
21.10.2013 2 Mon 21.10.2013 False
22.10.2013 3 Tue 21.10.2013 True
23.10.2013 4 Wed 21.10.2013 True
24.10.2013 5 Thu 21.10.2013 True
```